# Http metódo post, parametro data está passando sempre vazio (Angularjs + Laravel 5.2)

Tags: angularjs, laravel, http-post

Estou utilizando o angularjs + laravel para construir minha aplicação. 
A questão é a seguinte, possuo um $scope.frequencias, que contém algumas informações sobre a frequencia de um aluno. Fiz um foreach do angular para enviar esses dados para o banco, porém meu parâmetro data (que contem esse scope) está sempre passando como vazio.

Foreach:

```js
angular.forEach($scope.frequencias, function(value, i, frequencias){
      $scope.frequencia = [];

      $scope.frequencia = frequencias[i];
      url = frequencias[i].url;
      
      //Aqui é mostrado o scope que quero enviar para o banco, está correto
      console.log($scope.frequencia);
      //aqui é mostrada a url para o metodo, que também está correta
      console.log(url);

      
      $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: $.param($scope.frequencia),
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
              }).success(function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
              }).error(function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  alert('Um erro ocorreu. Check a log para mais detalhes.');
              }); 
              
    })
```

O controller do laravel, que recebe o scope e insere no banco

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controler;
use App\Frequencia;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Frequencias extends Controller
{
 public function salvar(Request $request)
 {
   
   $frequencia = new Frequencia;

         $frequencia->data_frequencia = 
              $request->input('data_frequencia');
         $frequencia->numero_faltas = 
              $request->input('numero_faltas');
   $frequencia->aluno_id = 
              $request->input('aluno_id');
   $frequencia->disciplina_id = 
              $request->input('disciplina_id');
  

         $frequencia->save();
         
 }

 public function update(Request $request)
 {
  
  $id = $request->input('id');

  
  $frequencia = Frequencia::find($id);

        $frequencia->data_frequencia = 
          $request-  >input('data_frequencia');
        $frequencia->numero_faltas = 
          $request->input('numero_faltas');
  $frequencia->aluno_id = 
          $request->input('aluno_id');
  $frequencia->disciplina_id = 
          $request->input('disciplina_id');
 

        $frequencia->save();
        
  
 }
}
```

As rotas utilizadas do laravel

```js
//rotas para frequencia

Route::post("/api/v1/frequencias/salvar","Frequencias@salvar");

Route::post("/api/v1/frequencias/atualizar","Frequencias@update");
```

Na hora que chega no controller, ele tenta inserir os parametros como null, e da erro no banco, pois alguns atributos sao uniques.
Faço a inserção dessa maneira em vários pontos da minha aplicação, e só nesse que está dando problema.
Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Quando envia post para o método precisa debugar no console do navegador, por acaso já fez isso...?

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se realmente esta sendo enviado o parâmetro "data_frequencia". Como geralmente uso chrome, em Developer Tools -> Network la possui o seu POST, ve se esta enviando algum valor.

E uma dica, use a variável value ao invés do array, por exemplo.

```
 angular.forEach($scope.frequencias, function(frequencia, index){

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: frequencia.url,
        data: $.param(frequencia),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert('Um erro ocorreu. Check a log para mais detalhes.');
    }); 

})
```

Comment: Não está sendo enviado nada... nem do seu jeito, nem do meu, não sei o que fazer